# Count row files in PostgreSQL with copy

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I'm loading data from multiple files in PostgreSQL with copy command bellow example

```
COPY product(title, department) from 'ys1.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

what i'm looking for is to write number of rows on each file and also file name loaded in separate table

```
ys1.csv : 1999
ys2.csv : 2565
```

and so on

is there a way in PostgreSQL to either do it with PL/pgSQL or with shell? or even php? any of those language would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to COPY's [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

> On successful completion, a COPY command returns a command tag of the
>   form
>
> COPY count
>
> The count is the number of rows copied.

To get this command tag in php, use [pg_result_status](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-status.php)  with `PGSQL_STATUS_STRING` as the second argument:

> mixed pg_result_status ( resource $result [, int $type =
>   PGSQL_STATUS_LONG ] )
>
> pg_result_status() returns the status of a result resource, or the
>   PostgreSQL command **completion tag** associated with the result

Comment: You can also use `GET DIAGNOSTICS` to capture it from PL/PgSQL.